# 3D Ray Casting / Picking

Tags: 3d, camera, raycasting

I am not sure if I should post this link, but I feel this falls into game development just as much as it does math. I have a ray cast's far and near values and I am trying to calculate the end point of the ray so that I can either draw a line to show the ray, or render an object at the end of 3d mouse position.

Here is my post on the stack overflow math site, if there is a problem with me doing this just close the thread. Thank you.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15918/help-with-matrix-mathematica

Comment: Please do not cross-post. And if you do, don't then link the question and instead paste it into this question box.

Comment: Ok ... raycasting is definetively good for gamedev (i think).

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that you don't know 3D position of the clicked point, because otherwise it would be easy :).

So if you know 3D position of the clicked point in origin basis then you can calculate far and near points like this:

```
nearPoint3D = cameraposition3D
farPoint3D = cameraposition3D + (normalize(clickedPoint3D - cameraposition3D) * zFar)
```

The problematic part is `clickedPoint3D`. You can compute it nicely with help of view and projection matrices. As you are using opengl i suppose that you have them. view * projection matrix converts 3D points to the 2D screen space. You can use inverted viewprojection matrix and get matrix which converts 2D screen points to the 3D space.

```
pseudo code and some openGl:

//define matrices
Matrix4x4 g_CameraViewMatrix;
Matrix4x4 g_CameraProjectionMatrix;

//read projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(...); //your perspective function
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &g_CameraProjectionMatrix.m[0]); //returns matrix as float array

//read view matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glLookAt(...); //you lookat function or whatever - NO translation,rotations or anything else for getting camera matrix!
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &g_CameraViewMatrix.m[0]);  

//compute 3D position of clicked point
Matrix4x4 viewProjInv = (g_LightViewMatrix * g_CameraViewMatrix).getInverse();
vector4D clickedPointOnSreen = (x_screen,y_screen,1.0f,1.0f); // Z have to be between 0 - 1 and W have to be 1
vector4D clickedPointIn3DOrigin = viewProjInv * clickedPointOnSreen; 
vector3D clickedPoint3D = clickedPointIn3DOrigin.xyz;
```

Note that you can use this to compute 3D points of zNear and zFar really easily:

```
vector4D clickedPointOnSreen = (x_screen,y_screen,1.0f,1.0f); // will produce 3D position of zFar
vector4D clickedPointOnSreen = (x_screen,y_screen,0.0f,1.0f); // will produce 3D position of zNear.
```

**Isn't that algebra wonderful? :)**

To learn something about projection matrix you can read this [what-is-the-purpose-of-the-canonical-view-volume](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6279/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-canonical-view-volume)

Comment: wow! and so this is how gluUnproject works?

Comment: @nkint Yes. From glu documentation: "gluUnProject multiplies the normalized device coordinates by the inverse of model*proj". Thats exactly what this code does.

Comment: @Notabene It's actually the inverse of proj*model, like you did in your example (if I assume `g_LightViewMatrix` means `g_CameraProjectionMatrix`)